# Setup IntelliJ IDEA to run one class app

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new with Java and I believe that my question is really stupid but still I can't find out correct answer.

I'm learning Java with the Horstmann's 'Core Java' book. And there is a first intro example there:

```
public class Welcome
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String[] greeting = new String[3];
      greeting[0] = "Welcome to Core Java";
      greeting[1] = "by Cay Horstmann";
      greeting[2] = "and Gary Cornell";

      for (String g : greeting)
         System.out.println(g);
   }
```

This code placed in Welcome.java file and it is only file in directory.
I can run it with terminal using

```
javac Welcome.java 
java Welcome
```

But I'm stuck with setting up IntelliJ IDEA to run this app. 
When I creating new Project, I choose "Application" type since it looks like most correct for this app. But then in project Config IDEA asks me to set main class there and module.

But this file has no Main class and any module and it works via cli, so I'm confused. Should I create some src dirs and modules to make IDEA run this app or I'm just missing something in the settings?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main class is in your case: `Welcome` .

As for setting it up in IJ: Just rightclick your class (Welcome) in the explorer (left side normally) and click the option "run Welcome.main()".

This will make your application run for it's first time and it should also create a runtime configuration so you can run it with either a keybind or a simple click of that green arrow on the top right.

[image: Run a class]

Comment: If rightclick on Welcome class I getting context menu and it hasn't any "run" lines. Also if I set Welcome as a Main class, Idea highlights it red with an error "cannot resolve symbol Welcome".

Comment: @Paul : do you perhaps have a screenshot of this? Afaik IntelliJ should recognize every class that has a `public static void main` method as a runnable class.

Comment: @Paul : Yes. Create a directory specifically for your code to live in.Intellij doesn't handle having code just under your module directory. The convention is to name that folder: src as in source code.

Comment: @Paul: Seems like there is not even a module folder and a src folder present. Try creating 2 folders: 1) with the name of your project, could be anything from "TwitterBotz" to "StackOverFlowTest". Be creative. Then rightclick the aformentioned folder and use the "Make module X" option. 2) In your newly created module, add a folder which will contain your source code. (Programmer convention dictates that this is 'src'). And on your 'src', rightclick, mark directory as 'sources root'. Your class / java file should reside in that 'src' directory.

Comment: @MiKickkiller also Idea doesn't show src dir but in terminal I see that it is present: http://i.imgur.com/h43845G.png

Comment: @Paul: Ah, then it's a case of Intellij not having a project open, but simply being used to edit a .java file. Try "File" > "Open" and then navigate to the folder just above src. Select this folder and open it in Intellij. This should create a project of your code.

Comment: yes, it creates the project, but still there is not "run" button. I opened directory and created 'src' dir manually. Tried to rightclick on java file - no "run" button. Tried to move it into src direcrory by myself - still no "run" button. Is this right structure now: http://i.imgur.com/PykhtGK.png ?

Comment: @Paul : Just 1 more step: Rightclick your src and select : Mark directory as "Sources root". After this step you should be able to run your class

Comment: Yes, I marked is as sources root and in settings now I was able to set welcome class as main class. But when I press "run" I get an error  “Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for module…”. Should I specify it? Is there some agreements in java world how to name them?

Comment: No real agreement there afaik. Most just use a folder 'out' that resides under the module root. To set the specific folder: Look towards the top right of your IJ window and just next to the spy glass, there's a button 'project structure'. Go here and set the variable 'Project Compiler Output' to wherever you want it to dump the compiled .class files. As mentioned: Many choose a folder 'out' that lives next to src, and under the module directory.

Comment: Ok this is getting really complicated / annoying. I would suggest you follow @Meo 's answer to make a full project and then just copy your x lines of code over.

Comment: Nope, It was completely my fault. I set output path as Idea suggested and I didn't make sure that that path existed. I believed that Idea is smart enough for this. Now it works like a charm. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially, a "Main" class is the class that contains `main` method in it with the following signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

In your case, IntelliJ wants you to specify the Welcome class you wrote.

A "module" in this context refers to something specific to IntelliJ which allows a project to have distinct modules with their own specific sources and classpaths.

Comment: For some reason Idea doesn't accept Welcome class as I main class: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZcrM.png

Answer (score 0):

Your project setup is wrong, because you do not have a module. The easiest is to just create a new Java project, select a `Command Line App` template and be done with it:
[image]